# RESTful search for deep nested resources

Tags: rest, api, web-services

I need to implement a search that in my head sounds more suited for SOAP than a RESTful service so I am struggling expressing it in as a REST endpoint.

### Domain Model

Company(**companyId**)
Contract(**contractId**, companyId, privilegeGroupId)
PrivilegeGroup(**privilegeGroupId**, privilegeId)
Privilege(**privilegeId**)

Primary keys in bold.

### Search in SOAP terms

findPrivilegesByCompanyId

### RESTify SOAP requests

I have tried in many ways to hammer this query to some kind of REST request but nothing is really convincing me because privileges and companies do not have a direct relationship.
The actual relation is represented by this long URI:

*/companies/{companyId}/contracts/privileged-groups/privileges*

However, even though this URI speaks the truth, it doesn't seem a good idea exposing it to the API clients. So I am trying to come up with some alternatives:

- GET /companies/{companyId}/privileges
- GET /privileges/search?companyId={companyId}

Any idea on how to handle those scenarios? How to express those kinds of queries in a RESTful API? Is it even possible? I think that in theory, the result of this query is not even a resource in REST terms.

Note: the API already exposes CRUD operations for each object of the domain model.

Comment: Are you analyzing the URI structure on each link you click in your browser while surfing the web or do you use the accompanying text describing the content the link points to? The same holds true for REST as it is just a generalization of the Web. Use meaningful link relation names rather than overengineered URIs. This allows you later on to change the URI structure without clients breaking as they will just invoke the URI returned for a certain link relation name. Note that the server should provide clients with all the necessary options to proceed with from the current state on.

Comment: Good point. But this API doesn't return links in the payload, it is not that RESTful. However, having a good URI would make the API easier to understand for the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that in theory, the result of this query is not even a resource in REST terms.

[It is](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1).

> The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. Any information that can be named can be a resource

In REST, the URI is just an *identifier* for the resource.  If we wanted to retrieve, for example, the privileges of Acme Corporation, this URI is perfectly "restful"

```
/7B7F1B30-7A84-4406-8D88-FAC9B647AC12
```

The spelling doesn't matter to REST.

Your implementation framework, and you API consumers, may prefer [hackable URI](http://www.ben-morris.com/hackable-uris-may-look-nice-but-they-dont-have-much-to-do-with-rest-and-hateoas/); but that's not a REST constraint.

Furthermore, there is no REST constraint that requires each entity in your domain model to have one and exactly one URI.  "Your resource model is NOT your domain model".

In short, if you have a single endpoint that produces a representation of this query result, and you need to encode into the identifier a company id to do the lookup, then these are all *fine*.

```
/7B7F1B30-7A84-4406-8D88-FAC9B647AC12/{companyId}
/7B7F1B30-7A84-4406-8D88-FAC9B647AC12?{companyId}
/{companyId}/7B7F1B30-7A84-4406-8D88-FAC9B647AC12
/7B7F1B30-7A84-4406-8D88-FAC9B647AC12;{companyId}
```

The hard part is trying to choose a semantically significant/recognizable spelling; essentially the same problem that you have when trying to name a variable in your code, and subject to similar restrictions -- ie: the compiler doesn't *care*, you are writing to communicate clearly with other human beings.

You might look to the use case you are supporting for ideas about spellings, but it's likely that you are providing some sort of privileges "summary", akin to a account summary or balance sheet.

Comment: Citing Fielding from the dissertation you linked: "The only thing that is required to be static for a resource is the semantics of the mapping, since the semantics is what distinguishes one resource from another.". So yes, queries are resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like there is no direct relation between the resources, you can use query parameters to filter based on another resource. 
Ex : /privileges?company_id=$company_id

(IMO, the word **search** you have mentioned in your sample url is not needed for this case. Even though search is what happens, it can also be considered as a filter using another resource id)